# How to delete rows 1-12 in a MySQL table

Tags: php, sql, delete-row

How would I go about doing this? I already have an id field with auto increment and primary key.  But yeah I need a script that does this.  Everywhere I looked it just shows me how to delete single rows but never multiple rows in order.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to `LIMIT` your delete to 12 rows, you will want to set it so that it deletes `WHERE` the `id` is `>=` to the id that it is due to start at.

If I want to delete 12 rows, starting at (and including) `id` 4, from table `foo`:

```
DELETE FROM `foo` WHERE `id` >= 4 ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define any order you like to delete the data. And with `limit` you can limit the number of records you want to delete

```
delete from your_table
order by id asc
limit 12
```